# How can I define SQL server connection string inside a class and use everywhere in project?

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio, class

I don't want to change connection string every where in my project. I want to
share a common definition.

It is possible to do everything related to database (e.g. insert, update, delete)   definee in that class?

I am using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Hey learn [ask]

Comment: Usually, you will want to keep connection strings in the config file of the application, not hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is on of the (many) possible solutions:

- You can store you connection string inside a **configuration file** (**app.config** if you're developing a desktop application or a DLL or **web.config** if you are developing a web service or a web application). Sample *.config* file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
          <add name="TestCfg" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xxx;IntegratedSecurity=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
  ```
- Then you can implement a **DAL** (*Data access layer*) that implements all DB-related operations (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) for more information)
- Finally your application should always access the DB using methods exposed by the DAL

Answer (score 2):

Create a static class dbHelper.cs and then use it throughout for insert, update, delete, etc.
See a pseudo code sample below.

```
public static class dbHelper
    {
        private static string conStr = "connection_string";

        public static int insertDeleteUpdateQuery(string query)
        {
            // use conStr to create connection string
            // open connection here 
            // execute your query
        }
    }
```

Use above class like this

```
dbHelper.insertDeleteUpdateQuery("ADO.NET query);
```

Answer (score 2):

A posible solution in VB.Net is make a master class and make others inherit from it.

```
Public Class wsMaster
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    Protected conn As String = "CONNECTION_STRING"
End Class


Public Class wsResport
    Inherits wsMaster

End Class
```

Or if you have a web.config add a connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;User ID=USERDB;Password=USERPASS" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I hope helps you